# Get build start time, end time, result, project name, etc?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I plan to write PowerShell task for Build pipeline. Are there any built-in variable for building start time, end time, result, project name, etc?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any built-in variable for building start time, end time, result, project name, etc?

I am afraid there is no such built-in variable to get the building start time, end time, result, project name, etc directly.

As you can see the comprehensive list of [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), there is no such built-in variables.

In order to get their value, we need use the PowerShell and Rest API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

The powershell scripts:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.1"
$buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$starttime= $buildPipeline.startTime

Write-Host This is start time: $starttime

$Endtime= $buildPipeline.finishTime

Write-Host This is end time: $Endtime

$result= $buildPipeline.result

Write-Host This is build result: $result

$projectname= $buildPipeline.definition.project.name

Write-Host This is project name: $projectname
```

The result:

[image]

**Update:**

> So I will need to create another pipeline for the rest api call and
>   trigger it from my Build pipeline? BTW, how to trigger it?

Yes, you need to create another pipeline for the rest api call. To trigger it, you can add CallAPI build as build completion:

[image]

In this case, when the build pipeline completed, it will trigger the rest api build.

> how to pass buildId to the new pipeline?

We could use [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API with definitions Parameters to list the build Ids for the specify build definition, like:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1&definitions={DefinitionId}
```

Then we could get the first build id, then we could use the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to set that Id as ENV variable：

```
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar2]testvalue2")
```

In this case, we could get that ID in the next task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where did you run the script? I got the finished time not set or state with the value of `inProgress` when running it on a powershell task. I think these attributes are not set when the task is running?

Comment: @ca9163d9, Yes, if the build is not complete, we could not get the finished time. So, we have to run this powershell task in other build pipeline after the that pipeline is completed.

Comment: So I will need to create another pipeline for the rest api call and trigger it from my Build pipeline? BTW, how to trigger it?

Comment: And how to pass `buildId` to the new pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a [long list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) of a pre-defined variable for the build pipeline.

If you use PowerShell inlnie you use them in this way:

```
$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

If the PS script is in a file you use them in this way:

```
$env:Build_BuildNumber
```

Comment: The predefined variables didn't have start time, etc?

Comment: @ca9163d9 No. Do you plan to run the PowerShell script during the pipeline or after it?

Comment: Either way is okay as long as I can get these information.

Comment: You can get build end time if the pipeline still running... to get all the info (start, end etc.) you need to use Rest API

Comment: Is there any document for Rest API? I cannot find some of the information I need, e.g. build start time, in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml.

Comment: Yes, check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1