# AzurePipelines: different values for `pipeline.startTime` in the same run of a pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a pipeline defined by the following two files. My problem is that the output of the `ShowDate` step is not the same in these two jobs. I would expect this because both are filled by `pipeline.startTime`. It seems that `pipeline.startTime` is evaluated in each job and the result is the start time of the job and not the pipeline itself.

So my question is: how can I get the start time of the pipeline itself? Or what am I doing wrong here?

When I run the pipeline I can see in the protocol of the job itself in section 'Job preparation parameters' that the right values are assigned to the variable `DateString` but this values are ignored.

azure-pipelines.yml

```
stages:
- stage: SomeStage    
  jobs:
  - template: job-template.yml
  - template: job-template.yml
```

and job-template.yml

```
jobs:
- job: 
  variables:
    DateString: $[format('{0:yyyy}_{0:MM}_{0:dd}_{0:HH}{0:mm}{0:ss}', pipeline.startTime)]
  pool:
    name: SomePool
  steps:
  - script: echo $(DateString)
    displayName: ShowDate
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: wait
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'Start-Sleep -Seconds 10'
```

Comment: You can make a call via REST API like it is shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903825/2347999

Comment: You could declare the variable at the stage level and pass it to the jobs as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can (mis-)use the `name` field to store the pipeline starte time.

eg:

```yaml
name: $(versionNumber)_$(Date:yyyyMMddHHmmss)
```

then access it via `Build.BuildNumber`. In the case above you would need to use the  [split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#split).

```yaml
variables:
  versionNumber: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'V', '')]
  pipelineStart: $[split(variables['Build.BuildNumber'])[1]]
```

In your case you may need to pass the variable as a [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-parameters?view=azure-devops) to the template.

There is an open issue about the missleading name of the `pipeline.startTime` variable. It is actualy the time when the agent starts and that differs from job to job.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/11535